# Calling Model from View (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeingiter and i am building a Simple Blog.

In Post table, i have "id, cat_id, title, content"... In category tablet i have "id, name"...

To display post,

i fetched contents from POST inside model using following function...

```
function get_posts(){
        $query = $this->db->get('post');
        return $query->result();
}
```

Then i load the view file to display the post... The above function fetch only the CATEGORY ID, but i need Category name... So i need to call model from view file... I think it is illogical to call Model from view... is there any solution???

Please help me...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as your model:

```
function get_posts(){         
    $this->db->get('post');         
    $this->db->join('category', 'posts.category_id = category.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Do check if the table and column names in the join section are correct. 'category' is the name of your category table, 
posts.category_id is the column in your posts table that refers to the category id, category.id is the id column in 
the category table.

You should be able to access the category name now.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
   $ci =&get_instance();
   $ci->load->model(your model);
   $ci->(your model)->(your function);     
   Note: You have to call your model in your controller.Its working fine
```

Comment: Super ;) Answar

Answer (score 4):

You can simply the call the model as you call in the controller like this

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');

$this->Model_name->function();
```

Or in case you dont want to call directly in the view you can get the data through the controller:

```
$categoryID =  $this->Model_name->function();
$categoryDetails =  $this->Model_name->function($categoryID);
$data = [
    'categoryID'      => $categoryID,
    'categoryDetails' => $categoryDetails
];
```

And then

```
$this->load->view('view name',$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the model from the controller and pass the data to the view:

Controller:

```
$data['posts'] = $this->my_model->get_posts();
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

View:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I already did this, what i am asking is, the above lines will return id, title, content & "CATEGORY ID"... but i need CATEGORY NAME (category name is in CATEGORY table)...

Comment: So make a join query with the Category table and return it as one of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which worked...

```
    function get_posts(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('post');
        $this->db->join('category','post.cat_id=category.id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```